# Org-mode code blocks do not inherit variable properties from enclosing nodes

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When playing with the literate aspects of Org-mode I found a description [here](http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/literate-devops.html) of how you can set up a `var` property of a node and how this would then be inherited by enclosed code blocks as a variable binding. So you could do something like:

```
* Some node
  :PROPERTIES:
  :var:      x=123
  ...
  :END:
```

And this would be equivalent to something like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x=123
  ...
#+END_SRC
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case in my Org mode, as I'm getting `eval: Symbol’s value as variable is void: x` when trying to execute the code block. I'm using Org-mode version `9.0.7` from Elpa. I've tried looking at variable `org-use-property-inheritance`, but was unable to get this to work. Any hints or ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using Org Mode 9. In contrast to Org Mode 8, you now have to specify header arguments within a header argument property:

```
* Some node
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :var x=123
  :END:
```

You can check out the documentation [here.](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html)